# Python tkinter filedialog disables menu on mac

Tags: python, tkinter, macos-mojave

When I open a filedialog with a menu button, the menu is disabled afterward, and I can't do anything with it.

How can I make the menu not disabled after the button click?

Info

- Python: 3.8.3
- OS: Mac MoJave 10.14.6
- TkInter: 8.5

Here's some sample code to reproduce.

Click `File` -> `Load` -> `Cancel`

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog


def load_file():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Open File')

    menubar = tk.Menu(root)
    root['menu'] = menubar

    menu_file = tk.Menu(menubar)
    menu_file.add_command(label='Load', command=load_file)

    menubar.add_cascade(menu=menu_file, label='File')

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Does not happen on Tkinter 8.6, try updating to 8.6

Answer (score 1):

[edit] It looks like this happens after I close and reopen my mac - putting it on standby. Restarting the mac completely fixes the issue.

---

Not sure what's going on, but I can no longer reproduce this. I guess the answer was reboot your machine?